# vscode Jupyter notebook run button missing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

Everything works fine when I first open vscode and create a new Jupyter notebook
[image]

When I save and reopen it, the run button is gone.
[image]

I have added "jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"] to setting.JSON and still no change
[image]
[image]

python is installed
[image]

Jupyter notebook installed
[image]

How can I make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks weird, the appearance of the `jupyter notebook` in your question is different from mine:

[image]

In my memory, it looks like the older version of the `jupyter notebook`.

Could you provide more info about the jupyter notebook you are using? Like this:

[image]

And could you try to reinstall the `Jupyter Notebook` extension and disable other extensions which may be related to `.ipynb` file?

Answer (score 1):

Use shift+enter and that should run the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the folder as a workspace and then, the button is shown. If you only open the file the result is that you can read the content, but not run the python code.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Steven-MSFT's answer, I saw that there was a button called "Reload Extension" indicated on this drawing below:

[image]

You can access this sidebar by entering cmd + shift + p, and then entering "Extensions: Install Extensions", as seen below:

[image]

Once I reloaded my Jupyter extension, all worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Uninstall and reinstall of "Jupyter" extension solved it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32723398)